# How can I reduce the visual effect of offset.left

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am using some Javascript that means when a user scrolls up and down, a block moves left and right.

The JS works perfectly but I cant work out how to reduce the level of movement to more of a subtle shift.

This is my JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


var offset = $(".post-slider-wrapper").offset();
console.log(offset.left);
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".post-slider-wrapper").css("left", st + offset.left);
});


});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make decrease the amount of scroll by dividing them with any factor:

```js
css("left", (st + offset.left) / 3);
```